# How can I format a date time to a specific, non-standard format in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

In c#, how could I format a date/time to get the specific output format?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow(); 
//Assuming the current UTC date/time is 6/14/2023 16:21 UTC
```

I need the following output string:

```
Wednesday 14. June 2023 16:21 UTC
```

Comment: There's a whole documentation page for this, and all you have to do is search for "[custom datetime format c#](https://www.google.com/search?q=custom+datetime+format+c%23)" ...  The first result is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings  Read the documentation, try something based on what you've read. If you have trouble with that, you can post a question about the specific problem you're having with that.

Comment: You don't say what you've tried but take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: `string result = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddddd d. MMMM yyyy HH':'mm 'UTC'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZozGuH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow(); 
string formattedDateTime = dt.ToString("dddd dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm UTC");
Console.WriteLine(formattedDateTime);
```